# "AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'encode'

Tags: python, arduino

Como dice el titulo, tengo este error en el cual al enviar un número al arduino para que cambie la variable de aforo maximo. Al iniciar pongo el número que corresponde y me salte el error `arduino.write(enviar.encode()) AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'encode'`,  os paso el código que tengo:

```
import serial

arduino=serial.Serial("/dev/ttyACM0",9600)

enviar=input("Introduce un numero de aforo maximo")

arduino.write(enviar.encode())
```

Comment: El código funciona perfecto. Por favor, agrega un `print(type(enviar))` y confirma que sea una cadena (`<class 'str'>`)

Comment: asi seria? arduino.write(print(type(enviar))?

Comment: No. La idea es imprimir en el terminal para que veas el resultado.

Comment: Pero lo que quiero hacerlo es enviarlo al Arduino este numero

Comment: Es para comprobar que estás pasando una cadena y no un entero.

Comment: y añadiendo eso en teoria deberia enviarlo al Arduino correctamente no?

Comment: Es posible que estés ejecutando con python2. En esa versión de python la función `input()` no devuelve una cadena, sino que intenta convertirla a un tipo más apropiado. En este caso te devolvería un entero y luego eso falla porque lo que necesitabas era una cadena. Si es esta la causa, cambia `input()` por `raw_input()`, que es la funcion de Python2 que lee cadenas. O mira si puedes ejecutar tu código con Python3 (recomendable)

Comment: Añades esas instrucción para "depurar" el código, para comprobar que valores estas usando.

Comment: ahora lo compruebo

Comment: Vale me funciona , Muchas Gracias

Comment: Josep, siento ser un pesado, pero el titulo de la pregunta es la parte generica del traceback que aparece en todos los errores y que en realidad no dice nada. ¿Podrías cambiarlo a algo como "AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'encode' " que es realmente el error?

Comment: Voy ahora lo cambio